# Dependence injections how is created instance of class?

Tags: php

I use dependence injections in own class:

```
class FeedFetcher {
 protected $cache;
 function __construct(Cache $cache) {
   $this->cache = $cache;
 }
}
```

How does PHP create instance of object here:

```
function __construct(Cache $cache) { $cache->method(); }
```

Why does it work if I there is not `new Cache()`? Why I can call `$cache->method();` witout creating instance of Cache?

Comment: you can call method if their method are 'static'. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Why not as: `__construct(Cache new $cache)`?

Comment: because dependency injection not work like this, on cause (new $cache) is best pratice extend class or use traits.

Comment: dependcy assumes your class is used by two different objects. please vote if help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cache $cache` is a [Type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) or type hint, stating that you must pass an instance of `Cache` when creating an object of `FeedFetcher`:

```
class FeedFetcher {
    protected $cache;

    function __construct(Cache $cache) { $cache->method(); }
}

// create a Cache object
$c = new Cache;
// pass Cache object to constructor of FeedFetcher
$f = new FeedFetcher($c);
```

If you don't pass an object of type `Cache` it will generate an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to FeedFetcher() must be an instance of Cache, none/null/something else given.